# can i modify underlaying webpack config in meteor angular2?

Tags: meteor, angular, webpack

I'm building a meteor app with meteor-angular2 package. But with .css it's quite unfunny so far.. As soon is try to import a css file in a component, meteor is "modules-loader" is telling that this is not a module i'm trying to import (true basically :D)

Now i'm fiddling around with a basic webpack+ng2 setup and i can get it easily running with direct imports of .css files in typescript - just because i can configure the webpack loaders correctly (you can even get css-modules in this way with ng2!)

So, in the docs of the latest meteor angular2 package release it is somwhere written that it is basically packing all the stuff with webpack.

What's the right way to modify this underlaying webpack config? Is it even possible? Do i have to fork the package repo to change it? At a first shot i didn't find the webpack stuff in there..

Comment: there is a package from the react community "meteor webpack" - it has a lot submodules for all purposes and it basically disables meteor as a package builder and integrates perfectly -> with that thing you can somehow control your webpack build